# App to run Chrome web extensions on iPad

Tags: ipad, android, web-browser, chrome-extensions

I have now moved from Android to iOS. In Android , I used [Yandex Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yandex.browser&hl=en) in which I can use Chrome web extensions. But in the Yandex Browser iOS app f, I can't download chrome web extension.

Does anyone know of a browser on iOS that allows the use of Chrome web extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such browser. The reasons are the [App Store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements), which forbid the execution of downloaded code (such as web extensions).

Your best bet is to download browsers with lots of features built-in like iCab or similar and hope it covers your use-case.

Otherwise, maybe you can achieve what you want by having a desktop browser running somewhere and connecting to that using screen sharing from your iPad…

Answer (score 0):

Browsers in the iOS appstore aren’t allowed to ship with what chrome apps and extensions need.
However, there are plenty safari extensions available in the appstore though.
Safari is a browser that also is built from webkit (the first), it comes pre-installed.